# Database must be null or a non-empty string during MediaWiki upgrade

Tags: php, mediawiki

I am trying to upgrade my media wiki from 1.27 to 1.28. I have done `composer update` but now when running `php maintenance/update.php` I'm getting the error

> Uncaught InvalidArgumentException: Database must be null or a non-empty string. in /home/xxxxxxx/yyyyyyyyyyyy/includes/libs/rdbms/database/DatabaseDomain.php:43

Does anyone have any ideas what's wrong?

It seems it's having false passed in somehow.

Comment: I assume everything is ok with your database settings in `LocalSettings.php` ?

Comment: My main DB settings are, as the sites still runs properly. I'm not sure if new required settings we introduced between 1.27 and 1.28.

Comment: Do you have a wiki farm, in which the wiki is chosen from web request headers, which will not work in command line?